# Creating a temporary element X made up of other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery print plugin that has the capability to print out particular elements from the page.

If I call `$('.main-container').print();` it will print out all elements within the main container.

However, there are many elements within the 'main-container' that I would not like to include in the element that is passed on to the print() function.

My question is, is there an a way to combine 3-4 elements into one and store that element in a variable so then I can pass this new element to the print() function leaving out all the elements I wish to not print?

Something like:

```
var $printThis = $('header').html();
$printThis += $('.middle-column').html();
$printThis += $('.footer').html();
$printThis.print();
```

Comment: You can use media queries and print-specific `media` attribute and just target and "hide" what you don't want to print, on print. Lot easier that what you describe. Give elements or blocks you don't want to print `display: none`, right?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll look into it. I never used css @media....

Comment: Take a look at this page, the source and `media="print"` stylesheet: http://rms.unt.edu Then look at the print preview. It works pretty well.

Comment: OK, I found the problem with 'print preview' in google chrome. If your main-container has a box shadow, the background color of the container will render as black. Remove the box shadow, and the background color returns to its a original color, weird!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use CSS @media print and hide the nodes you don't want to show.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does not answer my question at all. My question was how to combine elements in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery function `.append()`.